# What is required to show VSS Code Remote explorer

Tags: aws-glue

I'm trying to set up a local glue environment using VSS Code as source code controller.

I followed the instructions given in the the link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html#local-dev-restrictions

I'm not able to see any Remote Explorer on the left menu. I'm on Mac OS. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be there on the left side if you installed the Remote Development extension pack

[image]